# How to parse void* to PyObject

Tags: c, python-3.x, extension-methods

I want to write a wrapper for my C function as I want to call it from python code.So my wrapper function is

```
static PyObject* my_func_wrapper(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) 
{
    PyObject* obj_Ptr = my_func(); 
    return Py_BuildValue('O', obj_Ptr);
}
```

My C my_func() has no params, and return MyClass pointer converted to (void *).

When I run my setup.py script I'm getting this

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Py_BuildValue’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 Py_BuildValue('O', obj_Ptr);
```

and when I call my_func_wrapper from python I'm getting Seg.Fault Error in return line.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: "return MyClass pointer converted to (void *)." Could you please clarify this? Maybe show a "dummy" version of `my_func` that still reproduces the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the prototype of Py_BuildValue:

```
PyObject *Py_BuildValue(char *format, ...);
```

So the first argument should be "O" and not 'O'.

I'm not sure about you second arg either : you are using my_func() result instead of getting a pointer to this function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Warning message disappears after changing 'O' to "O". But Segfault error still exists.

Comment: You should be using &my_func instead of my_func() (pointer vs function return value)

Comment: again the same problem

Comment: I can't help you more because I don't know python :(